# Failed to implement Link.description, tried: in rails-graphql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql

When I tried to update object in graphql, I encouterd this image's error.

[encounter this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZhXU.png)

the code I wrote.

```
module Mutations
  class UpdateLink < BaseMutation
    argument :link_id, ID, required: true
    argument :description, String, required: false
    argument :url, String, required: false

    type Types::LinkType

    def resolve(**args)
      link = Link.find(args[:link_id])
      link.update!(
        url: args[:url],
        description: args[:description],
        user: context[:current_user]
      )
    end
  end
end
```

error messages here

> Failed to implement Link.description, tried:
>
> ```
>       - `Types::LinkType#description`, which did not exist
>       - `TrueClass#description`, which did not exist
>       - Looking up hash key `:description` or `"description"` on `true`, but it wasn't a Hash
>
>       To implement this field, define one of the methods above (and check for typos)
> ```

I don't know how to solve this error.

Please teach me how to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`link.update!` returns a boolean true (as it is the last line of the method), whereas the `resolve` method is expecting `Types::LinkType`. Try returning the link at the end of the resolve method.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply.
I resolved this error for your answer!